# Cartan matrices: motivation and intuitive examples?

Tags: matrices

could anyone provide me with a sketch of the motivation that gave rise to Cartan matrices in abstract (homological) algebra, Lie algebrae and so on? Which was the trigger or the need for them? It would also be great if you could provide me with some insightul and intuitive examples of their application in everyday life, so to speak.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any suggestions? ;(